# How do I move file from one Sharepoint folder to another in the Team Platform with the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

The scenario is there are Team A and Team B. When Team B is being created, can we reference the file from team A to also be in Team B.

Comment: This will almost certainly get closed, but you should be able to use the Move option in the ... overflow menu. Just go up a few levels to see all the Teams you have access to.

Answer (score 0):

I found an API that Microsoft graph provides that copies files and documents from one team's SharePoint site to another Team's Sharepoint site.

```
 POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/copy
 POST /groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{itemId}/copy
 POST /me/drive/items/{item-id}/copy
 POST /sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{itemId}/copy
 POST /users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/copy
```

I was able to successfully move files from one Team to another through graph api. I thought I had to go through SharePoint pnp and all to move files. Graph API is handling everything.

Comment: What did you use for request body? I tried the root drive item id from the destination site but the file is just renamed in its destination.

Comment: Hello @GabrielSmoljár `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/root:/General/{fileName}:/content?@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior=rename` thats the endpoint I used to POST request and for the GET request I used `"V1endpoint/drives/{DriveId}/root:/General:/children"`

Comment: OK but what about the request body in the POST?

Comment: `await HttpPost($"/sites/{siteID}/lists/{ListId}/drive/items/{ItemToCopyId}/copy",

                           new SharePointListItem
                           {
                               ParentReference = new parentReference
                               {
                                   driveId = DriveID,
                                   id = GeneralFolderId


                               }


                           });` Please mark the above as answer. Thank you